# Как ускорить код?

Tags: delphi, файлы

Нужно прочитать пикселы из файла.

```
f:=tfilestream.Create(path,fmopenread);
f.Seek($12,sofrombeginning);
f.Read(image.w, sizeof(integer));

f.Seek(22,sofrombeginning);
f.Read(image.h,  sizeof(integer));

f.Seek($36,sofrombeginning);

setlength(image.pixels, image.w*image.h+1);

for x := 1 to image.w*image.h do
f.Read(image.pixels[x], sizeof(TBGRA));

f.Free;
```

Comment: Может читать не по пикселу, а сразу, счесть весь массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считывание картинки попиксельно очень сильно нагружает как саму систему, так и основной поток процесса приложения(mainstream).
В данном случае нагрузку позволят снизить потоки. Создайте в своем приложении дополнительный поток. С ними работать очень просто, но зато они позволяют значительно снизить нагрузку на основной поток. Всю рутину обычно всегда выносят в отдельный поток. Многопоточные приложения более гибкие, реже падают от сильной нагрузки.

Comment: Значит, считывать всё сразу?

Comment: Да, свой код оставьте. Тут оптимизация не поможет. Просто вынесите этот код в отдельный поток.

Comment: Благодарю!

Comment: Пожалуйста =)

Comment: @Asen Очень интересное и явно обоснованное мнение про простоту работы с потоками. Особенно радует фраза про то, что многопоточные приложения реже падают от (`sic!`) *сильной нагрузки*. А, еще порадовал термин `mainstream`.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, Это хорошо)

Comment: Видимо, надо было обрамить мой предыдущий комментарий тэгами `<sarcasm></sarcasm>`.

Answer (score 4):

*Пойдем от простого и будем отталкиваться от готовых решений, уже имеющихся в `VCL`.*

Для манипуляций с изображениями в `VCL` предложены классы `TGraphic`, `TPicture` и `TCanvas` с соответствующими потомками, так или иначе расширяющими их функциональность:

[image]

- Теперь, глянув [**референс,**](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/!!MEMBERTYPE_Methods_Graphics_TBitmap.html) напишем код, использующий объект `TBitmap` для загрузки изображения из файла. При таком подходе работа с пикселями соответствующего битмапа будет осуществляться путем доступа к свойству `bitmap.Pixels`

  ```
  procedure LoadImageAndAccessPixels(...);
  var
    bitmap: TBitmap;
  begin
    bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      bitmap.LoadFromFile(...);
      bitmap.Pixels ...;
    finally
      bitmap.Free;
    end;
  end;
  ```
- *Медленно работает?* А вы уверены, что попытки оптимизации доступа к пикселям **приведут к реальному улучшению скорости работы** вашего приложения?

> - Этот вопрос обычно задается неспроста. Можно неделями сидеть и оптимизировать методы, которые в реальных условиях будут выполняться в лучшем случае раз в месяц.
> - Когда я предлагаю потратить свое время *(и время команды)* на оптимизацию какого-либо фрагмента кода, то я в большинстве случаев имею на руках *результаты профайлера* для нескольких реальных `test`-кейсов, которые показывают, что конкретная функция действительно съедает **значительную часть** процессорного времени.

---

- Допустим, вы знаете, что доступ к пикселям выполняется недостаточно быстро и из-за этого страдает конечный пользователь. Опять же, посмотрим, есть ли что-то готовое для улучшения производительность компонентов библиотеки `VCL`.
- Статья [**Fast Direct Pixel Access**](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Fast_direct_pixel_access) демонстрирует нам несложный способ подменить `TBitmap` на его более быструю реализацию, которой не требуется поддерживать различные форматы и осуществлять дополнительные проверки. После ознакомления со статьей мы меняем используемый **`TBitmap`** на [**`TFastBitmap`**](http://svn.zdechov.net/svn/PascalClassLibrary/GraphicTest/UFastBitmap.pas) и наслаждаемся приростом производительности.

> *Direct pixel access in libraries is
>   generally slowed-down by more factors:*
>
> - Coordinate limits checking
> - Facility for automatic image updating and redrawing
> - Abstract program constructions as property, static and virtual methods,
>     dynamic 2d arrays
> - Support for multiple pixel formats
> - Support for multiple platforms

- Чуть более общий подход, нежели тот, что был описан в предыдущем пункте - воспользоваться уже [**готовой библиотекой Graphics32**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphics32/), оптимизированной для пиксельных операций.

> Разумеется, *интеграция библиотеки* является более сложной операцией, нежели *интеграция одного стороннего класса,* однако этот вариант имеет вполне очевидные преимущества по сравнению с предыдущим.

Comment: Спасибо за вашу старательность, но в моём коде пикселы должны сохрянятся в массив, а не в Bitmap. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Собственно из приведенного кода (форматируйте, пожалуйста!) следует, что матрица пикселов располагается в файле непрерывно. Если же и в памяти она должна быть непрерывной, то единственная возможная оптимизация - чтение всех пикселов.

И там один сиротливый пиксел совершенно не к месту